# Combine: How to cancel a flatMap'ed publisher

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, combine

New to Combine & reactive programming here so the help is very much appreciated.

I have the following scenario: I'd like to build a UI where a user can filter down content via various 'filter' buttons on the page. When a user taps one of the buttons, I need to shoot off an API request to get the data.

Now, I have a publisher that provides me with the 'state' of these selections, and I've structured my code like this:

```
        state
            .publisher /* sends whenever 'state' updates behind the scenes */
            .debounce(for: 1.0, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .map { /*  create some URL request */ }
            .flatMap {
                URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: someRequest)
                    .map { $0.data }
                    .decode(type: MyResponseType.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        }.sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
            /// cancelled
        }) { (output) in
             /// go show my results
             /// Ideally, this is only called when the most recent API call finishes!
        }.store(in: &cancellables)
```

However, this implementation has a bug in the following scenario: If one event makes it through to the flatMap to fire off a request, and a subsequent event does the same before the network call completes, then we will call the completion handler twice.

Preferably, we are somehow a canceling the inner pipeline so we only execute the completion handler with the most recent event.

How can I 'cancel' that inner pipeline (the one started by the dataTaskPublisher) when new events come down the pipeline without tearing down the outer pipeline?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't want `flatMap`. You want `switchToLatest`. Change your `flatMap` to a plain `map`, then add `.switchToLatest()` after it. Because `switchToLatest` requires the failure types to match up, you may also need to use `mapError`. The `decode` operator produces failure type `Error`, so you can `mapError` to `Error`.

Example:

```
state
    .publisher /* sends whenever 'state' updates behind the scenes */
    .debounce(for: 1.0, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
    .map { makeURLRequest(from: $0) }
    .map({ someRequest in
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: someRequest)
            .map { $0.data }
            .decode(type: MyResponseType.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    })
    .mapError { $0 as Error }
    .switchToLatest()
    .sink(
        receiveCompletion: ({ (completion) in
            print(completion)
            /// cancelled
        }),
        receiveValue: ({ (output) in
            print(output)
            /// go show my results
            /// Ideally, this is only called when the most recent API call finishes!
        }))
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```